# Eclipse Java editor : errors no more indicated when typing

Tags: java, eclipse

In my classic java editor panel, errors are no more indicated when live typing but only when I save changes!?

(I talk about the red underline style on compile error)

I try to find in Preferences what configuration could affect this but I found nothing about this. I never saw that in eclipse, I've never had this problem and I used it for maybe 10 years now..

Comment: Did you uncheck "Build Automatically" under the "Project" menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Window**  → **Preferences**  → **Java**  → **Editor**  → Check "*Report problems as you type*":

[image]